# Como criar um for no R com os índices de um data frame

Tags: r, loop, for, data.frame

Se tenho um data.frame:

```
> dato<-as.data.frame(matrix(1:64,8,8,T))[-3,]
> dato
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
2  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
4 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
5 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
6 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
7 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56
8 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64
```

Como posso "chamar" o vector de índices (1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)?

Pois quero utiliza-lo como índice em um `for`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complementando a excelente resposta do @Marcus-Nunes, para obter os `indices` de forma automática do seu `data.frame`, você pode usar a função `row.names()`:

```
dato <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:64, 8, 8, T))[-3, ]

# selectionar o nome das linhas e converter caracteres em numérico
rw <- as.numeric(row.names(dato))
rw
# [1] 1 2 4 5 6 7 8
```

Usando `rw` num loop `for()`:

```
for(i in rw) {
  print(i)
}
# [1] 1
# [1] 2
# [1] 4
# [1] 5
# [1] 6
# [1] 7
# [1] 8
```

Answer (score 5):

O ponto chave aqui é perceber que todo `for` no `R` é executado a partir de um vetor de índices. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
for (j in 1:5){
  print(j^2)
}
[1] 1
[1] 4
[1] 9
[1] 16
[1] 25
```

Para fazer este loop, eu implicitamente eu criei um vetor de índices com o comando `1:5`:

```
1:5
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Em particular, este vetor começa em 1 e termina em 5, com incremento de 1. Se eu tivesse feito ele explicitamente *antes* de criar meu `for`, eu obteria o mesmo resultado:

```
indices <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
for (j in indices){
  print(j^2)
}
[1] 1
[1] 4
[1] 9
[1] 16
[1] 25
```

Portanto, o `for` no `R` está definido em cima das posições de um vetor. Este vetor pode ser o que eu bem entender. Vamos supor que eu deseje elevar ao quadrado não os cinco primeiros números inteiros positivos, mas os cinco primeiro números primos. Assim eu teria

```
indices <- c(2, 3, 5, 7, 11)
for (j in indices){
  print(j^2)
}
[1] 4
[1] 9
[1] 25
[1] 49
[1] 121
```

Percebe como a lógica é a mesma? Eu só preciso definir corretamente o meu vetor de índices e fazer meu contador variar nele. No teu caso, seria algo como

```
indices <- c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
for (j in indices){
  # comandos a serem executados
}
```

Claro que o vetor `indices` poderia ter sido definido de uma maneira menos explícita. Por exemplo, o comando

```
indices <- (1:8)[-3]
[1] 1 2 4 5 6 7 8
```

cria um vetor com os oito primeiros números inteiros positivos e retira a observação presente na terceira posição.

Enfim, há diversas maneiras de resolver o problema. A única característica que não muda é que o `R` vai sempre fazer o contador do loop variar nas posições de um vetor, da primeira até a última.